# MLE of $\frac{1}{\theta}$ Uniform distribution.

Tags: statistical-inference

Let $X_1,X_2...X_n$ be a random sample from $U(\theta-5,\theta+5)$ where $\theta \in(0,\infty) $ is unknown. Let $T=\max(X_1,X_2...,X_n)$ and $U=\min(X_1,X_2...,X_n)$. Then which of the following statements is TRUE?

$(A) \dfrac{2}{T+U}$ is M LE of $\dfrac{1}{\theta}$

$(B) MLE$ of $\dfrac{1}{\theta}$ doesnt exist

$(C)U+8$ is MLE of $\theta$

$(D)\dfrac{T+U}{2}$ is unique MLE of $\theta$

$\theta-5<x_{(1)} < x_{(2)}....x_{(n)}< \theta+5$

$\theta<x_{(1)}+5$ and $\theta>x_{(n)}-5$

$x_{(n)}-5<\theta<x_{(1)}+5$

Any statistic satisfying above condition is MLE of $\theta$ so there is no unique MLE here option $(D)$ rules out

$x_{(1)}+8<x_{(1)}+5$

Option $(C)$

$8<5$ which is false so option $C$ is false.

I am not sure how to prove $(A)$ and $(B)$ but in the exam, I have ticked $(B)$ so am I right?   If I am wrong can anyone prove how?

Comment: Is D supposed supposed to be (T+U)/2?

Comment: @Stacker Yes I am sorry

Comment: I think it is D because if min is 5 and max is 15 then it has to be (5+15)/2

Comment: @Stacker There are no other estimates which satisfy the condition except $D$? what about $\frac{T+U}{4}$

Comment: It's not D. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy What is it then ? is it B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\theta\in \mathbb R$, any MLE of $\theta$ can be expressed as a convex combination $X_{(n)}-5$ and $X_{(1)}+5$:

$$\hat\theta_{\alpha}=\alpha(X_{(n)}-5)+(1-\alpha)(X_{(1)}+5)\,,$$

where $\alpha\in (0,1)$ is free of $\theta$.

Under the restriction $\theta>0$, MLE is $\hat\theta_{\alpha}$ provided $\hat\theta_{\alpha}>0$. If $\hat\theta_{\alpha}<0$, then technically MLE of $\theta$ and hence MLE of $1/\theta$ does not exist.

So for $\alpha=\frac12$, one MLE of $\theta$ is  $\hat\theta=\frac{X_{(n)}+X_{(1)}}{2}$ if $X_{(n)}+X_{(1)}>0$. Then $1/\hat\theta$ is guaranteed to be one MLE of $1/\theta$ provided $X_{(n)}+X_{(1)}>0$.

So I think the correct option among (A) and (B) depends on the sample observed.

Comment: its $A$ then got it

Comment: $A$ or $B$ ? tell me that

Answer (score 1):

Because of the equivariance of MLEs, the MLE of $1/\theta$ is the reciprocal of the MLE of $\theta.$

The joint density is
$$
\begin{cases} 1/10^n & \text{as long as $\theta$ is so located that} \\
& \text{the interval $(\theta\pm5)$ includes} \\
& \text{both $U$ and $T$,}  \\[6pt] 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}
$$

So $\theta$ must be in the interval $(T-5,U+5)$ in order that the likelihood be positive; otherwise the likelihood is $0.$ **Except** that we have this complication: If it is known that $\theta>0,$ then one must use instead $(\min\{T-5,0\},\, U+5).$

Thus one can say there is a non-unique MLE: Any number in that interval will serve.

Comment: I am confused which answer is correct ? Your explanation rules out $C$ and $D$.

Comment: @Daman : My suspicion is that whoever wrote this intended to say there's no MLE because the maximum is not unique. But that's just a matter of conventional definition.

Comment: [here](https://prnt.sc/1003b8u). Can $A$ be correct ?

Comment: @Daman : One could say that's one of the non-unique values of the MLE, except in the case I mentioned of the observed maximum being less than $5.$

Comment: I am not able to understand Michael please just tell me for now which option you would ve ticked. I will discuss this later I just gave an exam.

Comment: C and D are plainly wrong. B is correct only if one regards uniqueness as essential to what an MLE is. A is right EXCEPT in the cases I mentioned, where the maximum is less than 5.

Comment: I see but only one option is correct in my exam so can I challenge this question as "Less information if given"

Comment: @Daman : How did your instructor state the definition of MLE? As I said, this instance involves a question of convention that does not arise in most instances.

Comment: Its not about my instructor. This question came in the entrance exam. Admission in masters for the whole country.

Comment: @Daman : Were you told to rely on particular textbooks to prepare for the exam?

Comment: No. https://jam.iisc.ac.in/p/mathematical-statistics-ms-1

Comment: what about stubborn atoms answer?

Answer (score 1):

This question really boils down to whether you're allowed to divide by 0 or not. Suppose that you have a sample $X_1,...,X_n$ with $U=\min\{X_1,...,X_n\}=-1$ and $T=\max\{X_1,...,X_n\}=1$. Then we can agree that any $\theta\in[-4,4]$ is an MLE of $\theta$ because the indicator variables in the likelihood is 1 (as opposed to 0). That is, the inequality

$$T-5\le\theta\le U+5$$

holds. Then by the invariance property $\left(\frac 1 \theta\right)_{MLE}=\frac 1 {\theta_{MLE}}$. That is, $\left(\frac 1 \theta\right)_{MLE}\in(-\infty,-\frac 1 4]\cup[\frac 1 4,\infty)$. In particular, $\frac{T+U}{2}=0$ is an MLE of $\theta$, but $\frac{2}{T+U}$ is **not** an MLE of $\frac 1 \theta$ because it is undefined. However $\left(\frac 1 \theta\right)_{MLE}$ do exist, as previously mentioned being in the interval of anything smaller than -1/4 or greater than 1/4.

It is helpful to determine the difference between maximum likelihood **estimators** and maximum likelihood **estimates**. Note that $\frac{T+U}{2}$ is a MLE of $\theta$ that works for all samples - in fact it is the only estimator that works for all samples. By the invariance property of maximum likelihood estimators, we can conclude that $\frac{2}{T+U}$ is a maximum likelihood estimator of $\frac 1 \theta$, even though as in the example in the previous paragraph, its maximum likelihood estimates that it produces may be undefined when U=-T, whilst other MLEstimates exist for 1/theta.

**Conclusion**
$\frac 2{T+U}$ is a Maximum Likelihood Estimator of $\frac 1 \theta$. Since it does not exist when the denominator is 0, it is also true that it is a MLEstimator of $\frac 1 \theta$ when this happens.

Eliminate:

(B) It is too specific. A MLE of 1/theta only doesn't exist when U=-5 and T=5. 2/(U+T) doesn't work for when U=-T and $U\ne-5$, but MLEs of 1/theta always exist in these cases.